# How to stop re-opening of firefox browser again & again to see the changes?

Tags: firefox-addon

I am working on a firefox extension. The problem is if I make any change in it, I need to close and then re-open firefox browser to see the changes . Is there any way I can see those changes by just refreshing the page ?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try the [Restart Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10749/?src=api) plugin to see if that improves your experience.

Comment: That's what I do for changes in overlays. Also if your changes are not made in the main window (browser.xul) but in, for example, a sidebar (or a dialog, another window, etc) and you disabled xul cache (nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache = true) in the preferences, you can just open and close the sidebar to reload.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Extension Developer Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7434/) for this. There is a "Reload Chrome" button that will do exactly that. It won't alter the browser interface, though, so I generally navigate to my extension's chrome:// URL in a browser window. When I have made significant changes and am ready to test the real extension again, then I'll restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, no.

If you're just editing the XUL then you can test different things by using the DOM Inspector to edit/insert/delete elements and properties to see what they will look like without restarting Firefox. You can also use the JavaScript console to test some JavaScript. I've found these things to be a big time saver when developing extensions, but anytime you make a change to the extension code itself you will need to restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use chromeedit, or firebug to a degree.  There used to be a plugin for firebug called chromebug.

What I do is to create a batch file that calls 7-zip and creates an archive from all the files I need, then rename the extension from zip to xpi.  Then I use the same batch file to copy the extension to the Firefox directory, with the extension's correct name (the one used in the install.rdf file).

Now, I don't call that batch file directly.  Instead, I run a auto-hotkey script that first closes firefox, then creates the xpi using the batch file, then copies the xpi to Firefox's extension directory (with the right name), then restarts the browser for me.

In this way, I call a single command to create the addon, install it, and restart Firefox.  It takes about 10 seconds before I can resume my testing.